# Mail Automation Task using Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, email-attachments, outlook-object-model

**I had been trying to automate the process of sending mails along with attachments via my outlook account using Powershell.**

```
$OL = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application

Start-Sleep 5

<#
olAppointmentItem
olContactItem
olDistributionListItem
olJournalItem
olMailItem
olNoteItem
olPostItem
olTaskItem
#>

#Create Item
$mItem = $OL.CreateItem("olMailItem")

$mItem.To = "PlayingWithPowershell@gmail.com"
$mItem.Subject = "PowerMail"
$mItem.Body = "SENT FROM POWERSHELL"

$mItem.Send()
```

*Stuck with adding attachments in the code.
Please help me out.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments).

In your case something like:

```
$mItem.Attachments.Add( "C:\My Documents\Q496.xls", olByValue, 1, "4th Quarter 1996 Results Chart"
```

Arguments are Source, Type, Position & DisplayName.